# How to concatenate string of a column and update the string in another table at the same time with using Cursor

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement wherein I have a `#ValidationList` table in which we have recorder all the validation error found in the imported data.

Following is the snapshot of data in `#ValidationList` table:

```
Id  ErrorMsg
1   Asset  # Unknown 
1   Unique Name and code is needed
2   Unique Name and code is needed
2   Asset  # Unknown 
3   Asset  # Unknown 
3   Unique Name and code is needed
4   Unique Name and code is needed
4   Asset  # Unknown
```

Now all these errors strings need to be updated in the original staging table #ImportedStagingData after concatenated with delimiter for same IDs.

As of now we are using cursor to update the errors in the original table:

```
declare Errors Cursor for
        Select DISTINCT Id from ##ValidationList

    Open Errors

    Fetch Next from Errors into @Id      

    while @@Fetch_status = 0      
        begin

            set @ErrorMessage=null
            SELECT @ErrorMessage = COALESCE(@ErrorMessage, '') + ' / ' + ErrMsg
                        FROM (SELECT ErrorMessage as ErrMsg
                              FROM ##ValidationList
                              WHERE Id = @Id) [ErrMsg]

            update #ImportedStagingData 
            set ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage
            where Id = @Id

            Fetch Next from Errors into @Id
        end

    close Errors
    deallocate Errors
```

Is there any way we can remove this cursor implementation and use SET BASED approach for better performance. Kindly suggest.

Comment: STUFF + XML and you rather don't need CURSOR at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Concatentation use [XML + STUFF trick](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/):

```
UPDATE i
SET ErrorMessage = STUFF( (SELECT '/' + v.ErrorMessage 
                             FROM ##ValidationList v
                             WHERE v.Id = i.Id
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '')
FROM #ImportedStagingData i;
```

This solution is `SET based`. You should avoid loop/cursor because `ROW by ROW` processing is very inefficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot @lad2025, the solution suggested by you has worked as expected. I wish to learn XQuery(XML) to an advance level, request you to please suggest me any resource in case you like to.

Comment: @PS078 [xml course](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/using-xml-in-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-8747) for free and for SQL Server ;)

Comment: @PS078 See also [XQuery Labs](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10279/xquery-labs-a-collection-of-xquery-sample-scripts.aspx)

Comment: Thank you once again for your suggestions and help :)